# Showing images with Rails from database

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, database

I'm trying to show a specific type of image that I've "stored" in the database onto the view. I have a model for "products" and a model for "images" as I have several types of images for each product (such as "gallery", "featured", "unboxing image" which are simplely stored as an attribute of type 0, 1 or 2)

I've put this into the HTML:

```
<%= image_tag @product.images.where(image_type: 2).first, :alt => 'product_image' %>
```

When I click to inspect element, I see this:

```
<img alt="product_image" src="/images/#<Image:0x007fcba329f4c0>">
```

Can someone please explain why what is happening? It looks like it is searching for the image in my assets/images folder but what is that #< and such in there? My image is stored as like lamp.png in the database.

This is my Image model:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base

  include AASM

  belongs_to :product
  mount_uploader :file, FileUploader

  validates :image_type, presence: true


  enum image_type: [IMAGE_UNBOXING.to_s, IMAGE_GALLERY.to_s, IMAGE_FEATURED.to_s]

  aasm column: :image_type do
    Image.image_types.keys.each do |state_string|
      state state_string.to_sym
    end

  end

end
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post your image model please

Comment: did you try to precompile your assets?

Comment: you need to pass  a url to src of image_tag..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@product.images.where(image_type: 2).first` returns a first record from database, but for `image_tag` you should specify `url` or `path` for returned records.

Use `url` attribut or what you have:

```
<%= image_tag @product.images.where(image_type: 2).first.url, :alt => 'product_image' %>
                                                         ^^^
```

Comment: I tried this, but I get an error when it loads: undefined method `url' for #<Image:0x007fcba3274928>

Comment: I pointed out that it is necessary to use an attribute that returns the full path to your image. I can't know it is `url` or `path` or `image_path`. Show your image model attributes.

Comment: follow your model  it should be something like `@product.images.where(image_type: 2).first.file.url` or `@product.images.where(image_type: 2).first.file.path`

Comment: @Kumo open `rails console` and find last image what you have, `Image.last` and show me all attributes what you see.

Comment: #<Image id: 4, image_type: 1, file: "lamp.png", product_id: 1, created_at: "2015-04-24 07:37:01", updated_at: "2015-04-24 07:37:01">

Comment: ok, show me please what returned if you run `Image.last.file` and tell what upload framework you use.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening: image_tag uses object#to_s method which returns the model identyfication

## <> is used to tell you, that this is an object

Image - class of object
0x007fcba329f4c0 - id of object instance

The *_path helper is avalible for controllers only, as they are the ones the request (browser) interacts is.

I'd create a separate controller ImagesController with only #show action. Then display the image in the view (eg <%= @image.data %>). Then the image_tag would take image_path(@product.images.where(image_type: 2).first).

Just make sure, that you are sending the correct MIME type:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Mime/Type.html