# How do I display image file from database in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a beginner at Ruby on Rails and Database stuff and I am having a hard time researching how to display image from PostgreSQL and Sqlite3 database to my website using Ruby on Rails, or in Ruby on Rails.

And my problem is "how to display images from database to my website using Rails", just that.

I started with `<%= @real_estate.image %>` in my `show.html.erb` and then what displays to my website is nothing useful like
`#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000000000d4fb548>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showing images with Rails from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29843018/showing-images-with-rails-from-database)

Comment: I strongly recommend using `ActiveStorage` to do this, it is really complete and easy to setup, after this, you can implement it in all the models you want without needing additional migrations It comes by default with Rails since version 5.2 Checkout [this docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html) to setup and use.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<%= image_tag @real_estate.image, :alt => 'product_image' %>
```

My recommendation is to strongly use some cloud storage(like s3 AWS) instead of being inside the database.
In the database, save only the url and name of the image.

The [fog gem](https://github.com/fog/fog-aws) can link your database information with s3 and bring a signed image url.